# Replace string in Nth array

Tags: bash, sed

I have a .txt file with strings in arrays which looks like these:

```
    id | String1 | String2 | Counts
    1  | Abc | Abb | 0
    2  | Cde | Cdf | 0
```

And i want to add counts, so i need to replace last digit, but i need to change it only for the one line.

I am getting new needed value by this function:

```
$(awk -F "|" -v i=$idOpen 'FNR == i { gsub (" ", "", $0); print $4}' filename)"
```

And them I want to replace it with new value, which will be bigger for 1.
And im doing it right in there.

```
counts=(("$(awk -F "|" -v i=$idOpen 'FNR == i { gsub (" ", "", $0); print $4}' filename)"+1))
```

Where IdOpen is an id of the array, where i need to replace string.

So i have tried to replace the whole array by these:

```
counter="$(awk -v i=$idOpen  'BEGIN{FNqR == i}{$7+=1} END{ print $0}' bookmarks)"
N=$idOpen
sed -i "{N}s/.*/${counter}" bookmarks
```

But it doesn't work!

So is there a way to replace only last string with value which i have got earlier?

As result i need to get:

```
id | String1 | String2 | Counts
1  | Abc | Abb | 1 # if idOpen was 1 for 1 time 
2  | Cde | Cdf | 2 # if idOpen was 2 for 2 times
```

And the last number will be increased by 1 everytime when i will activate these commands.

Comment: Please state clearly your input and _expected_ output. It will be easy to help you out that way!

Comment: Added the result, hope  it will help.

Comment: *2 # if idOpen was 2 for 2 times* - shouldn't be `3`(as it already has `2` in the second row) ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest thar was my mistake, in the beginning it has a value 0, every time when this script will be started and i will chose number as an IdOpen, value must increase by 1, it is just a counter of opens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

setting `idOpen` variable(for ex. `2`):

```
 idOpen=2
```

---

```
awk -F'|' -v i=$idOpen 'NR>1{if($1 == i) $4=" "$4+1}1' OFS='|' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

The output(after executing the above command twice):

```
cat file

id | String1 | String2 | Counts
1  | Abc | Abb | 0
2  | Cde | Cdf | 2
```

---

`NR>1` - skipping the *header* line